# How to vectorize when using fplot function?

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization

I am using fplot. 
(I could use plot as well I just found more examples of fplot).
I want to plot two straight lines of the form y = m * x
where m = V1 and V2. V1 and V2 are scalars.
The following code gives me an error.

Matlab Code

```
fplot(@(x) V1,[-4 4],'green')
xlim([-4 4])
ylim([-4 4])
```

The error messages say to vectorize. I am not sure how to do this? 
I will be later adding to this graph a specified grid using meshgrid funtion.

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-4:.5:4,-4:.5:4);
```

What bothers me is that I am not specifying increment .5 in the fplot statement.
The Matlab Code

```
fplot(@(x) V1,[-4 4],'green')
```

gives the following error messages:

Error Messages
Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To
improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return output with the same size and shape as the input arguments.

```
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine>getFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/updateFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function_I
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine
  In fplot>singleFplot (line 234)
  In fplot>@(f)singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 193)
  In fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 193)
  In fplot (line 163)
  In m01 (line 121)
```

Can someone help me put this together? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you've asked at least 9 MATLAB questions in the last 2 weeks, and they all seem to follow the format "I'm stuck doing X, here is my error". The questions aren't too bad, but **it feels like you're often dealing with an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/358485)**. Try to add more context about what you want to *achieve*, for instance this Q is really nothing to do with vectorizing functions. This can improve question quality because it makes us understand more, and will help you learn how to solve problems more than how to get over hurdles.

Answer (score 2):

The function handle given to `fplot` should implement the `y(x)` function you want to plot. So if you want to plot the `y = V1*x` line, you need to multiply `V1` by `x` in your function handle, like this:

```
fplot(@(x) V1*x,[-4 4],'green');
```

Your code was trying to plot the `y = V1` function, which is just a constant. MATLAB expects the output of the function handle to be of the same dimension as `x`, but since your function always returns a scalar `V1`, it doesn't work as expected (hence the warning). If you really want to plot a constant function, you can get rid of the warning by doing:

```
fplot(@(x) V1*ones(size(x)),[-4 4],'green');
```

Answer (score 2):

> You said that you want to plot two lines with the equation y = m*x,
>   where x is a vector and m is scalar V1 and V2 and hence you want to
>   plot 2 lines for both the scalar on the same plot.

So you can directly put the anonymous function in fplot() command using both V1 and V2 one by one.

```
close all

% declare the x interval
x =[-4:1:4];


% declare the m values as V1 and V2
V1 = 3;
V2 = 4;

% plot the 1st function
fplot(@(x)V1*x, 'green')
% hold the axis to plot the
% 2nd function within the same axis
hold on
% plot the 2nd function
fplot(@(x)V2*x, 'red')

xlim([-4 4])
ylim([-4 4])
hold off
```

> One most important thing to be noted while declaring a function is
>   that you must use the **dot (.) operator** while declaring the function if
>   applicable to **vectorize** the function correctly.

e.g.,

```
y = @(x)x.^2 + 2*x;
```